# Type hints for inherited classes does not work in mypy

Tags: python, subclass, mypy, type-hinting

I'm having issues with type hints for inherited classes. How can I provide a type hint that says *"any class that inherits from..."*?

Found what I though to be the solution, but I still get an error from mypy (see attached image).

```py
from typing import List, Type

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, parent: Type[A]):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, parent: Type[A]):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent


o_a: A = A()
o_b: B = B(parent=o_a)
o_c: C = C(parent=o_b)

things: List[Type[A]] = []
things.append(o_a)
things.append(o_b)
things.append(o_c)
```

[image]

Comment: You enter just `A` instead of `Type[A]`?

Comment: mypy is correct; the `parent` argument you're passing is an *instance*, not a class, hence the types don't match. But what are you actually trying to implement here? Why do instances of subclasses need to be passed instances of the parent class?

Comment: I'm trying to say that "parent" can be any class that inherits from A? If I dont do that, it appears passing a instance of type B as parent (as done when instancing C) also yields an error, which is why I started looking at this.

Comment: Perhaps I have just misunderstood something basic then. This post got down-voted immediately, so I probably did something stupid.

Comment: @knut: You're not passing classes that inherit from `A`. You're passing *instances* of those classes. Such instances are also instances of `A`, but they are absolutely not classes of any sort.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies, I mean I want to have a type hint that works for objects that are instances of any subclass of A. But somehow that appears to work in this code, but not my main project. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

So removing the the Type[A] does make sense here. I misunderstood the notation, and thought the Type[A] hint meant any object of a type that inherits from A, which is not the case. Instead this means the class type A itself.

Thank you for the replies. The problems in the project that caused me to write up this example must be something else then.

```py
from typing import List, Type

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, parent:A):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

class C(A):
    def __init__(self, parent:A):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent


o_a: A = A()
o_b: B = B(parent=o_a)
o_c: C = C(parent=o_b)

things: List[A] = []

things.append(o_a)
things.append(o_b)
things.append(o_c)
```